# How to solve this TensorFlow 'NameError: name 'tf' is not defined' error?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, opencv, python

I tried to change the value of `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` from 0 t0 3 and so on, so that I can try to access my external webcam, but I am unable. Following is the error I am facing in Jupyter notebook

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\MIRZAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14320/2909626117.py in <module>
     16     #     np.mean(image_np, 2, keepdims=True), (1, 1, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
     17 
---> 18     input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 3), dtype=tf.float32)
     19     detections, predictions_dict, shapes = detect_fn(input_tensor)
     20 

NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
```

Comment: did you import tensorflow as tf ?

Comment: `import tensorflow as tf` ?

Comment: As rightly mentioned in the above comments, you should `import tensorflow as tf` and try again it will resolve above issue. If Tensorflow was not installed on your system, you can try as `pip install tensorflow`. For more details you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install). Thanks!